# How to get a JSON object from a list with dictionaries (single quote to double quotes)

Tags: python, json, list

In my python script I want to do a rpc call which takes a JSON array as arguments.

```
rpc.command(JSONarray1, JSONarray2, 0, true)
```

to get the JSONarrays, I created lists with dictionaries as elements. the dictionaries hold strings as keys and strings or floats/integers as values.

```
mylist1 = 
[
    {
        'tixid': 'c1636efe3d85e3bb7e58663cfa976590ed1a9bb6740e7b851cbb34ab63f52ab9',
        'vout': 2,
        'sequence': 4294967293
    },
    ...,
]

mylist2 =
[
    {
        'bc1q0eg3madqa38t5usru66nvjzgqkdc7qz9n9qemw': 0.0001
    },
    ...,
]
```

When I pass mylist to the rpc call I get an error.
"value is not a string as expected"

The problem is, that python is using single quotes for strings in mylist.
I know, python does not care if you use single or double quotes for a string, but the rpc call I am using does...

I tried to use `json.dumps(mylist)`.
problem is that json.dumps() returns a string which the rpc call can't handle - needs JSON array. Same goes for `json.dump()` in to a file and use `json.load()`

I tried `numpy.array(str_mylist)`. But rpc call again can't handle this array - needs JSON array.

Any suggestion how I can "force" my python script to use double quotations for strings in mylist?

Comment: When you say: `json.dumps() returns a string which the rpc call can't handle`, why can't it handle a string? You already said that you see: `"value is not a string as expected"` when you pass a list in.

Comment: json.dumps() returns mylist as string. and a string can not be used as a json object by the rpc call. but the rpc call can handle strings inside the json object

Comment: *All* JSON values are strings; that's what JSON is: a string encoding of data structures.`json.dumps(mylist)` is the right thing to do, if the RPC really expects a JSON array of objects as its argument. Have you looked at the value returned by `json.dumps(mylist)`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a valid call to `rpc.command`? Something like `rpc.command('[{"id": "...", "sequence": 12949, "out": 1, "in": 1.1}]')` is what I expect you need, unless `sequence`, `out`, and `in` are supposed to be strings as well, not numbers (as suggested by user10133842).

Comment: okay, i should have been more specific from the beginning.
RPC call: `createrawtransaction [{"txid":"hex","vout":n,"sequence":n},...] [{"address":amount},{"data":"hex"},...] ( locktime replaceable )`
[link](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/)

Comment: mylist for Inputs = 
`[{'tixid': '29581ee2c355b703035a5fa3bfe38a3fb206fe16d189d4c1f41091410cff2f5e', 'vout': 12, 'sequence': 4294967293}]`

mylist for output = 
`[{'bc1q0eg3madqa2lt583745uzjvngqkdc7qz9n9qwme': 0.0001}, {'bc1qupkj09jdyhdzdwn2agc2mex2vwmlegfte3yjqe': 0.02121144}]`

here I get: error: JSON value is not a string as expected

Comment: if I use json.dumps(mylist) I get all the strings in "" instead of ''. But get error: "Expected type array, got string". therefore I assume the rpc dose not see json.dumps() as a json array but as a string instead

Comment: Ok, so what is `rpc` and `command` and what is this `type array` that it expects?

Comment: rpc = bitcoin-cli (from BitcoinCore),
command = createrawtransaction,
type array = JSON array

here is a link to the documentation of the [rpc.comand](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/rawtransactions/createrawtransaction/)

Comment: I don't think that's the link you are looking for, What is there is for command line usage. You need some python documentation.

Comment: link is correct. this is the command I want to execute with my python script. my bitcoin server (node) is setup to receive rpc.commands. connection and execution is working. my python script can call other rpc.commands (without JSONarrays) and they get executed correctly from my bitcoin node. But with this command I am running into errors with the JSONarray.

Comment: I'll check if I can finde specific python documentation for bitcoin rpc.commands...

Comment: I am using python-bitcoinrpc https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc, which is a fork of python-jsonrpc, to generate die RPC calls in python as described here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)

Answer (score 0):

"value is not a string as expected" appears to be pointing to the non-string values of 'sequence','out', and 'in'. If your rpc call is expecting a string, then you may need to set the values of 'sequence','out', and 'in' as strings instead of integer or float. e.g. 'sequence':'12949' instead of 'sequence': 12949

Comment: I have tried this. even if I set all keys and values as strings. I still get the error: "value is not a string as expected".

I assume the problem is (as stated in the original post), python sets strings in lists with single quotes ('string') and not double quotes ("string"). And the single quotes in the json array do not appear as a string to the rpc call

Comment: The Python representation of its own data types is irrelevant to the question of what JSON you need. `json.dumps(mylist)` will produce a string value containing double-quoted strings.

Comment: if I use json.dumps(mylist) I get error: "expected type array, got string"...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's related, but you're missing the comma after the key-value pair `'out': 1` in the first object, and `'out': 2` in the second, which in itself would cause the json formatter to freak out.

Comment: my bad - you are right, but that is just missing in the example code in this post. not in my script. edited the original post

Answer (score 0):

I could narrow it down and found the fault in my code causing the error.
I got a typing error for a key value in mylist1. I was using "t**i**xid" instead of "txid".

I found it a little confusing though, that the error was "value is not a string as expected". I would expect "**key** is not a string as expected" in this case. since it's a dict with key:value pairs. or is that different in a json array?

anyhow, script is running now. Tanks for all the inputs an support!